# I want to make a app which can extract information from the chat and add entry in calendar for specific messages using natural language processing

Tags: calendar, nlp, opennlp

I want to make a app which can extract information from  the chat and add entry in calendar for specific messages using natural language processing.

for example if we get message something like this in our chat app 
   "Meet me today at 8:00 pm on xyz street."

then our app should make entry in calendar for time, location and title of an event.

So please suggest me how to proceed and what give idea about brief steps to implement this using natural language processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for identifying patterns in text, I would recommend a look into regular expressions(Regex), I don't know what environment you are working with, but `grep` is the standard command line interface for it. [This](http://www.regexr.com) is a good place to start learning Regex.

Python is also a good language to deal with string manipulation and/or regex given it's simplicity. A basic knowledge in Regex+Python can solve your problem in a couple of lines.

I also don't know which calendar you want to create the entry on but there is a google calendar API for python [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python).

Good luck!

Comment: I want to implement this in android and the calendar I am going to use is that of android's default. Now I think that opennlp may help in get work done but I am confused in how to move further after parts of speech tagging.

Comment: @VimalPatel the link I provide sends you to the Google API library. You can use that for Android. Cheers!

Comment: @VimalPatel if my answer was useful in someway, please upvote it. If it was an actual answer of your question, please mark it as an answer. Also, I would recommend you to read the guidelines of so.

Comment: I want to implement that using natural language processing because nlp is my domain of project and the android application i want to make is just the demo of implementation of nlp.

Comment: NLP is an area that makes use of a set of tools as regex, for example. You can also use stanfords nltk library to identify the dates on the text, and go from there.

Comment: I am using apache opennlp. So give me some guide on how to proceed further and what steps it involves.